# What do you call the sheet (of fabric, nylon, etc.) that you lay on the carpet for everybody to sit around and have a meal?

Tags: single-word-requests

In some cultures, families who don't eat at a table use it regularly in their houses. It's used almost exclusively for serving food and eating, not for sitting on, covering the floor, etc.

[image]

Comment: There may be a word that's rarely used in English borrowed from a culture/language where this is common. Some examples of which countries use these and what they call them might help.

Comment: @ChrisH Well, in Persian we call it _sofreh_ (سفره), but I don't know how that's gonna help. I tried a bilingual dictionary myself and didn't find anything better than "tablecloth".

Comment: Well it does depend who you're trying to communicate to, but it seems like this might be a case where there's not really an English word that means exactly the right thing so you might be best off using the Persian word and explaining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider, ***spread***.

> : a cloth cover for a table or bed [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spread)

Comment: _Spread_ sounds good! But _picnic_ , as I said under Michael's answer, is not relevant. I would go with _spread_ if nothing better were to be found.

Comment: One rare occasion other than eating in which some Persians use this thing, is the wedding ceremony. [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_marriage#Sofreye_Aghd_.28Wedding_Spread.29) has called it a _wedding spread_ , so I'm going to call it a _spread_ in general, or more particularly: _eating spread_ .

Comment: @Fard Sounds good. Just be sure, though, that the context in which you'll use "eating spread" is crystal clear... https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22eating+spread%22&biw=522&bih=342&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRgOPs-bPJAhWB1BoKHVV7A5AQ_AUIBigB

Comment: Note that *spread* has many meanings; usually in the context of feasts (and certainly in that Wikipedia article) it means the whole meal, including decorations, condiments and other things. The word can mean 'a cloth', but as it says in the definition, it has be be spread *over* something else.

Comment: @TimLymington That's another thing that heartens me to use _spread_ : before every meal they spread it out over the floor and when they're done they clean it and fold it up.

Answer (score 5):

I've heard them called *picnic blankets* before:

[The 6 best picnic blankets of 2021](https://www.businessinsider.com/guides/best-picnic-blanket)

This is used for outdoor occasions.  For indoor, I would use the name for it in your own language, "We spread the / an **X** on the ground / floor before dinner."  As you know, English can accommodate words and ideas from other languages.  This often happens for foods, such as "hummus" or things such as a "hookah."  You can call a "hookah" a "water pipe," but I think the original is much better.

Comment: Around here some people use it three times a day in their houses. It's not for picnic. And besides, a picnic blanket is not exclusively for serving a meal.

Comment: @Fard well let's see what other people come up with.  These aren't used in the west indoors but outdoors.

Comment: @michael_timofeev, in the UK this is probably the most common term, can you include a definition?

Comment: @Fard Just call it what it is called in your language.  "We spread the X on the ground."

Comment: @Christopher maybe you'll have better luck than I did, but I couldn't find anything useful...mostly picture definitions or the word used in sentences.

Comment: Every language can accommodate words and ideas from other languages, and this is a considerable choice, if there's no exact match. +1. But trying to construct or adapt a native word would serve the language better sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

In English, the name for this item is the disappointingly generic "eating mat."

See e.g. [Baluchi eating mat or soffreh from Iran or Afghanistan](https://collection.maas.museum/object/399297) for an image.

Comment: This is a weird yet new approach to this problem and I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use sofreh. This would be the correct transliteration of the Arabic سفره which is the same sound as the Farsi mentioned before. We do transliterate a lot of other foreign words into English letters. Why not with this?

See Wikipedia's [Persian Wedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_wedding#Sofreh_Aghd_(Table_of_Wedding)) page which confirms the term *sofreh* as a fabric spread.

Comment: Hi Aisha, welcome to EL&U. As *sofreh* doesn't appear in any standard online dictionary, I'm not sure whether this qualifies as an "answer" - it would have been better as a comment. Adding comments is a privilege you can quickly earn by posting good questions and answers here. Anyway, I'll add a link to a relevant page, but feel free to [edit] your answer yourself to provide any additional supporting evidence.

Comment: It is not that we could transliterate everything like this. English has its words to combine and make something which works for this.

Comment: Sofreh is widely used in articles on Persian customs, as well as being used as a name for Persian restaurants and in western stores catering to the Persian furnishings market. Just because something isn't in a dictionary, doesn't mean it isn't a word: if you followed that principle language would never change (this SE is about usage not dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say "lay the tablecloth on on the floor". In this way the original English word "tablecloth" with its original meaning is kept.

Answer (score -1):

Whilst @michael_timofeev's picnic blanket is probably the most common term, you can use **groundsheet.** Its normally used inside of a tent, but I've used and seen one used for outdoor eating/picnicking on numerous occasions.

**Groundsheet** is defined by [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/groundsheet) as:

A sheet of waterproof material that is spread on the ground, often beneath a tent, and upon which a person may sit or sleep.

Comment: Yes; also called a _ground cloth_. But I wonder if there's a word that is used only for serving food and eating.

Comment: I'd certainly associate groundsheet with sleeping (in a tent or outdoors) rather than eating.